# Getting the last id from empty mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a mysql table where the `id` column is set to `AUTOINCREMENT` and a `PRIMARY KEY` is associated with it. If my table has some records in it already then to get the last id I query like this

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
$sql->execute();
```

Now considering my last record `id` is say about 224, then all the rows get deleted due to some function maybe. Then I want the last `id` for another querying purpose in which I want to add 1 with it.

```
$tobeinserted = $lastid + 1;
```

But since all the rows get deleted, I cannot query like the previous one. So how do I get it?

Comment: You do not need to do it. If not truncated the auto-increment will not be deleted. So the next insert will insert id = 225

Comment: No. I don't want to insert into that table. Before inserting into that table I need the id that is to be inserted for the purpose of doing some other task. If this task is accomplished then I will insert

Comment: read the auto_increment value from table ddl

Comment: Even I get the value how do I print it? like I print things in this way echo $row['id']

Comment: select * from `information_schema`.`tables`
  where table_name like 'afs_tipo_immagine' yes